# Drag Box2d Bodies on Touch

Tags: c++, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have two box2d bodies, one is static and other is dynamic. Now i have joined the static body with dynamic body through `b2revoluteJoint`. So my question is:

1) How do i move Dynamic Body on `touchMoved` along with static body which is attached at the same position on the dynamic body.

2) How do i move more than two bodies. Let suppose i have a human body, and the legs and hands are joined with `b2RevoluteJoint`. Now how can i move all the bodies together to create a natural look.

I am completely new in box2d so having some difficulties. Any one please help me regarding this issue.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For dragging objects in box2d is mouseJoint. In touchBegan you create a mouse joint with object that you want move and any static body for example groundBody, but in this joint this can be every static body. In touchMoved you change the position of mouseJoint. In touchEnded destroy joint :)

2) you can create more revoluteJoints for example leg and main body are jointed and arm and main body are jointed too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a MouseJoint to move the dynamic body, but the motion may not look "natural".

You can use "Seek" behavior to move a single body towards a touch point.  You will need to establish limits on how fast you want the body to move and also transform the touch point on the screen into a point in box2d world space.  Once you do that, you can use a function like the one below to move the body towards the touch point. Call this operation on your entity each physics update cycle.

```
   void MoveToTarget()
   {
      // Get the distance to the target.
      Vec2 toTarget = GetTargetPos() - GetBody()->GetWorldCenter();
      toTarget.Normalize();
      Vec2 desiredVel = GetMaxSpeed()*toTarget;
      Vec2 currentVel = GetBody()->GetLinearVelocity();
      Vec2 thrust = desiredVel - currentVel;
      GetBody()->ApplyForceToCenter(GetMaxLinearAcceleration()*thrust);
   }
```

I have used this successfully for missiles and moving things with some success ([see blog post here](http://nonlinearideas.com/viewports/)).  The source code is also available on the site.

You can connect multiple bodies and move them using them pure physics.  But this is **REALLY** hard.  I had a similar problem creating spiders for another project and found it was best to use a 2-D skeletal animation tool ([Spine](http://esotericsoftware.com/)) and then just lay a reasonable shape (Spiders are really big blobs so a sphere handled it nicely) over the body in box2d to handle moving it and collision detection.

**On the other hand, I created a snake using a series of balls connected by revolute joints.  With the seek behavior on the first (biggest) ball, the motion looks really nice.**

Was this helpful?